# Using unicorn or passenger without nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, load-balancing, unicorn

I've been reading up on `rails` deployment and it seems for the two options I'm considering, `unicorn` and `passenger`, the tutorials always put them behind a server like `nginx`.  I was under the assumption that both `unicorn` and `passenger` were fully functioning web servers themselves. So

1. Why are they always placed behind something like `nginx`?
2. If I use a load balancer `nginx` or `HAProxy`, can I have the load balancer directly distribute requests to `unicorn` or `passenger`, or do I still have to place them behind `nginx`?

Answer (score 2):

Unicorn must be placed behind Nginx, [by its author's design](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/PHILOSOPHY.html). The [Phusion Passenger Design & Architecture](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Design%20and%20Architecture.html#_the_rationale_behind_reverse_proxying) document explains why some app servers are designed to be placed behind Nginx. Basically, it has got to do with I/O concurrency handling and I/O security.

Phusion Passenger however does *not* need to be placed behind Nginx. Phusion Passenger integrates *into* Nginx, as an Nginx module. Even the Standalone mode of Phusion Passenger does not need to be placed behind Nginx, because its Standalone mode utilizes a lightweight Nginx core and thus already properly implements I/O security.

If you use HAProxy, you can have it directly connect to Unicorn as long as you configure HAProxy to perform both request and response buffering. For Unicorn, buffering is key. Phusion Passenger on the other hand doesn't care, it works fine regardless of whether you configure buffering or not.